# In measure theory, what is an example of a set of not well-defined area in unit square in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I am trying to understand the need of sigma-algebras in probability spaces. In https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/199280/why-do-we-need-sigma-algebras-to-define-probability-spaces the following example is given

> Consider this example. Suppose you have a unit square in
> $\mathbb{R}^2$, and you're interested in the probability of randomly
> selecting a point that is a member of a specific set in the unit
> square. In lots of circumstances, this can be readily answered based
> on a comparison of areas of the different sets. For example, we can
> draw some circles, measure their areas, and then take the probability
> as the fraction of the square falling in the circle. Very simple.
>
> But what if the area of the set of interest is not well-defined?
>
> If the area is not well-defined, then we can reason to two different
> but completely valid (in some sense) conclusions about what the area
> is. So we could have $P(A)=1$ on the one hand and $P(A)=0$ on the
> other hand, which implies $0=1$. This breaks all of math beyond
> repair. You can now prove $5<0$ and a number of other preposterous
> things. Clearly this isn't too useful.

What does it mean for a set $A$ to be not well-defined in this example?

Also, How could we have both $P(A)=0$ and $P(A)=1$ at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We cannot *really* have $P(A) = 0$ and $P(A) = 1$ at the same time (of course not, because $0 \neq 1$). It simply is not possible to assign $P(A)$ a value in a reasonable way.

What the post talks about is the impossibility of having a well-defined Lebesgue-measure for *all* (maybe extremely complicated) subsets of the unit square.

There are set which have "inner measure $<$ outer measure" which can be seen as the contradiction you wanted to understand. See for example [How does the Vitali set violate the definition of measurable sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1366182/how-does-the-vitali-set-violate-the-definition-of-measurable-sets?rq=1).

Comment: I have heard about Vitali sets before but I am specifically referring to the $R^2$ example. What is an example of not well defined set here?

Comment: Consider for example $N \times [0, 1]$ where $N$ is a Vitali set in $[0, 1]$:.

Comment: It isn't Lesbegue-measurable. If it would be, then $N = \{x \in [0, 1] \,\vert\, (x, y) \in (N \times [0, 1]) \}$ would be measurable for almost all $y \in [0, 1]$.

Answer (score 1):

"The measure of a set not being well-defined" means (per def.) that the set is not in the $\sigma$-algebra over which the measure is defined and the set cannot be added to the $\sigma$-algebra and the measure be extended to the new $\sigma$-algebra without violating some requirement of "being a measure".

I.e. these are sets, such that no matter which value you assign to them, you arrive at a contradiction, if you assume your measure satisfies the definition of "being a measure".
That's probably what was meant by "having $P(A)=0$ and $P(A)=1$ simultaneously".
Note that for different measures, different sets may be non-measurable.

There are two resolutions: adapt the properties a measure needs to have, or allow some sets to be non-measurable. Because we often *need* the properties of a usual measure, we allow non-measurable sets.

This is no problem, because (informally) such sets are "impossible to write down explicitly" so they won't appear in any real-world numeric problem.

Examples of such non-measurable sets are the [Vitali sets](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set) or those involved in the [Banach-Tarski paradox](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox). The former is easier to understand.

Edit to answer comment:
As @unwissen said, if $N$ is non-measurable (wrt. some measure on $\mathbb{R}$), then $N \times [a,b]$ is non-measurable (wrt. the corresponding product measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$).
In many situations you can take the cartesian product with a simple enough set, to lift a counterexample from a lower dimension to a higher one.

Comment: What are the Vitali sets in this $R^2$ example?