# Show that $\mu(A \bigcup B) = \mu(A) + \mu(B) - \mu(A\bigcap B)$

Tags: real-analysis, summation

Let $\mathcal{R}$ be a ring on $S$. Let that $\mu:\mathcal{R}\to[0,1]$ is additive.

**Question:** How do I prove that for $A,B\in\mathcal{R}$, $\mu(A) < \infty$, one has $\mu(A \bigcup B) = \mu(A) + \mu(B) - \mu(A\bigcap B)?$

*What I've tried:*

Pick $A_1 = A\backslash B, A_2 = B\backslash A$ and $A_3 = A\cap B$. Then $\mu\bigg(\bigcup\limits_{j = 1}^3A_j\bigg) = \mu(A\bigcup B).$ Furthermore $A_1 \bigcup A_3 = A$ and $A_2 \bigcup A_3 = B$. So we have that $\mu\bigg(\bigcup\limits_{j = 1}^3A_j\backslash A_2\bigg) = \mu(A)$ and $\mu\bigg(\bigcup\limits_{j = 1}^3A_j\backslash A_1\bigg) = \mu(B)$. I feel like I'm there if I rewrite the union, but I can't find out how.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noting
$$ A\cup B=(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)\cup(A\cap B)$$
and
$$ (A\setminus B)\cap(B\setminus A)=\emptyset,(A\setminus B)\cap(A\cap B)=\emptyset,(B\setminus A)\cap(A\cap B)=\emptyset$$
so the additive property, one has
$$ \mu(A\cup B)=\mu(A\setminus B)+\mu(B\setminus A)+\mu(A\cap B). \tag{1}$$
Also noting
$$ A=(A\setminus B)\cup (A\cap B), B=(B\setminus A)\cup (A\cap B)$$
one has
$$ \mu(A)=\mu(A\setminus B)+\mu(A\cap B), \mu(B)=\mu(B\setminus A)+\mu (A\cap B). \tag{2}$$
From (1) and (2), it is easy to obtain
$$ \mu(A \cup B) = \mu(A) + \mu(B) - \mu(A\cap B).$$

Comment: Is the given equation works for $\mu=\mu^*$ the outer measure, where $A,B\in{X}$ and at least one of them is $\mu^*$ measurable?

Comment: I think it works for outer measure too.

Comment: Yes, how it could be shown then, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake: Outer measure is a measure, see this link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1364526/is-outer-measure-a-measure